# foldmethod setting ignored when initializing vim

Tags: folding

I have the following in `after/ftplugin/vimwiki.vim`

```
setlocal foldmethod=expr
setlocal foldenable 
set foldexpr=VimwikiFoldLevelCustom(v:lnum)
```

I know this file is loading because if I put a syntax error in the file, vim throws and error when opening a vimwiki file.

However, to get the custom folding to kick in, I have to manually type `:set foldmethod=expr` in command mode to get the custom folding I want. Once I do that, folding works as desired.

But why isn't the `foldmethod` set to `expr` as soon as I open a vimwiki file? Instead it is set to `syntax`. I tried various combinations of

Answer (score 1):

Found the culprit using:

`:verbose set foldmethod?`

This told me that taskwiki last set the value in an autoload file. Uncommenting line 19 in `taskwiki/autoload/taskwiki.vim` did the trick:

`setlocal foldmethod=syntax`

Looks like taskwiki is relying on some old vimwiki variable that is not used anymore.

If you use views, the problem won't be completely solved until you delete the associated views in .local/share/nvim/views directory or manually set `foldmethod` for each file manually from the command line.